What happens if you try to use Gandharva Ville's Chasm entrance before completing "Chasm Spelunkers"?
The steps of "Chasm Spelunkers" unlocks access to the rest of the Chasm's areas, one of them being the other side of the Chasm entrance from Sumeru.
Is it possible to use the Sumeru entrance before finishing Chasm Spelunkers, even though it exits somewhere unlocked by Chasm Spelunkers? If so, what happens?
